# Opening all links with class popup in a new window

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have lots of links on my page with `class="popup"`.

I want all of these to open in a new window.

Any nice way to define this with JavaScript?

Comment: Why use JavaScript for this? Add `target="_blank"` to the anchor element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using `.live()` to support links that might be added later to the DOM. If you are not adding links from event handlers, Ajax callbacks, etc., you can simply use `.click()`.

```
$('a.popup').live('click', function (e) {
     window.open(this.href);
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Please note, that according to the current HTML5 spec, you can also use:

```
<a href="#" target="_blank"></a>
```

as you previously could in HTML4. This way, you do not need Javascript. Using `target` is not recommended though on an XHTML doctype, because it is not considered a valid attribute.

**UPDATE:** [From the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().

If you need help changing your code, be sure to check previous StackOverflow questions. Using the SO search  [[jquery] live deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D%20live%20deprecated) is a good start.

Comment: @Nikita: there *is* a jQuery tag in the question.

Comment: There is the jquery tag in the question

Comment: The `target` attribute was revived in the HTML5 spec. so there's no reason to use a JavaScript-method for this. Even though it's not valid according to XHMTL specs all browsers still have support for it.

Comment: The above code can be useful if you don't have access to the source but should be enough to just set the `target` attribute. Anyhow if you decide to use this method I'd like to add that returning `false` will effectively disable any other event handlers that was bound to `click`. You should rather use [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) and not return anything in the lambda.

Comment: @Marcus I have updated my answer based on your comments. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can put this in your `$(document).ready()`

```
$('a.popup').attr('TARGET', '_BLANK');
```